# exiftool as dependency for snap app

Tags: snap

I am unable to figure out how to add [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html#Unix) as dependency to my snap application.

Here is my snapcraft.yaml:

```
name: phockup
version: '1.2.0'
summary: Photo and video sorting tool
description: |
  ...

grade: devel
confinement: devmode

apps:
  phockup:
    command: phockup

parts:
  phockup:
    source: https://github.com/ivandokov/phockup.git
    source-tag: v1.2.0
    plugin: python
    install: |
      mkdir -p $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/bin
      cp phockup.py $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/bin/phockup
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add a section as part of your 'phockup' part.

```
stage-packages:
  - exiftool
```

This will stage exiftool inside your snap.

Comment: `Error downloading stage packages for part 'phockup': The package 'exiftool' was not found.`

Comment: The package is called `libimage-exiftool-perl` in the repos. When I use this name I get another error: ```tar: ./usr/bin/pstruct: Cannot hard link to ‘./usr/bin/c2ph’: Operation not permitted
tar: ./usr/bin/perlthanks: Cannot hard link to ‘./usr/bin/perlbug’: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 2``` and I am running `sudo snapcraft`

Comment: I'm sorry to bumping this thread, but I couldn't find any solution @popey. Any ideas?

Comment: @IvanDokov the error I get after adding the stage-package is this one:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24870552/
In order to use perl in the confined environment of the snap, you have to set some environment variables like in https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/blob/master/kpcli/run.sh
So, I would suggest you to make a part for exiftool, and use a wrapper instead of calling it directly.

Comment: Since this is my first snap ever I'm struggling completing the steps you described above. I've tried a few things, but I get different errors. PS: I saw the source of the exiftool does not require any compilation. It is possible to copy/paste the binary `exiftool` and `lib/` directory to the required place and it will work.